# Mixin render function composition

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, mixins

With vuejs mixins you can compose method data and many other stuff but render function does not play well. Is there a way to have partial template that can also be mixed in component ?

Something like this:

MyMxn.js

```js
export popupTemplate = function render(h) {
};

export default {
 ...
}
```

MyComponent.vue

```vue
<template>
  <div>
    << popupTemplate >>
    ....
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { MyMxn as default, popupTemplate } from "MyMxn.js";
export default {
   mixins: [MyMxn]
}
</script>
```